# Using jquery blur with input having brackets[] with this.val and ajax together

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This maybe easy for some of you, I'm have inputs with names with brackets, when the one gets a value I want to query the database using ajax to get the part number and put the value in the first empty pn[] field.

My HTML is:

```
<td>Record ID<span class="switchRed">*</span><br>
<input type="text" name="ri[]" id="ri" size="8" style="font-size:0.9em;" class="do_stuff"></td>
<td>Part Number<br>
<input type="text" name="pn[]" id="pn" style="font-size:0.9em;" class="readlock" readonly></td>
```

My Jquery / Ajax is

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("[name='ri[]']").on("blur", "[name='ri[]']", function() {
        var rival = $(this).val($(this).val());
            $.ajax({
                url: "/inventory/get-part-number.php",
                type: "post",
                data: "record=" + rival,
                // callback for success
                 success: function(data, textStatus) {
                     $("[name='pn[]']").each(function() {
                         if(!$(this).val() ) {
                         $(this).val(data); //put value in empty pn[]
                         }//end if
                     })//End each
                  }, //end success else...
                  //if failsauce throw error
                  error: function() {
                      alert('Learn To Code');
                     } //end error failsauce
                  }); //ends .ajax function
               }); //end blur
            }); // ends ready function

  </script>
```

The get-part-number.php is a simple mysql_query..

$message='';

```
    if(isset($_POST['record'])){ $record_id = $_POST['record']; }else{$record_id='';}
      //Get Part Number
      $sql="SELECT p.part_number FROM parts p JOIN received r ON r.part_id=p.part_id WHERE r.received_id='$record_id'";
      $query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
          $message.=$row['part_number'];
      }
        echo $message;
```

I have been un-succesfull in many variations to get the pn[] field to populate with results for the ajax request.

Can anybody see something wrong in my code and offer some advice.

Thank you

**SOLUTION via smclark89 and Musa**

Changed Jquery/Ajax from Above to:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("[name='ri[]']").on("blur", function() {
        var rival = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/inventory/get-part-number.php",
                type: "post",
                data: "record=" + rival,
                // callback for success
                 success: function(data, textStatus) {
                     $("[name='pn[]']").each(function() {
                         if(!$(this).val() ) {
                         $(this).val(data); //put value in empty pn[]
                         }//end if
                     })//End each
                  }, //end success else...
                  //if failsauce throw error
                  error: function() {
                      alert('Learn To Code');
                     } //end error failsauce
                  }); //ends .ajax function
               }); //end blur
            }); // ends ready function

  </script>
```

Comment: I believe this line: " $("[name='ri[]']").on("blur", "[name='ri[]']", function() {", should be: " $("[name='ri[]']").on("blur", function() {"

Comment: Why are you doing `$("[name='ri[]']").on("blur", "[name='ri[]']"`?

Comment: Also this doesn't look right `var rival = $(this).val($(this).val());`

Comment: smclark89, and Musa were spot on! Edit solution into post thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `.on` for delegation, the element you bind to must be a container of the element you delegate to. So it should be:

```
$(document).on("blur", "input name='ri[]'", function() { ... });
```

You can substitute a more specific element for `$(document)` -- the only requirement is that this must be a static element that's an ancestor of the dynamic `ri[]` elements.